# Loop through Functions in asynchronous

Tags: javascript

I have a few function that I'm looping through.

Here is what I have:

```
start() {
    this.loop();
}

one() {
    // Do stuff here
}

two() {
    // Do stuff here
}

loop() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.one();
        this.two();
        this.loop();
    }, 5000);
}
```

I need it to loop in the background without stopping the flow if the application.

How can I do this?

Comment: [How about `setInterval`?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!
Javascript is single threaded, which means it is not possible to run functions parallel in the background.

Comment: Are you performing any asynchronous operations?  From the example it's not clear to me exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: not possible....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises), something like this:

```
one() {
    return new Promise(resolve=>{
        // Do stuff here
        resolve();

    })

}

two() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        // Do stuff here
        resolve();

    })
}

loop() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.one()
          .then(()=>this.two())
          .then(()=>loop())
    }, 5000);
}
```

Of course, you'll end up with an infinite loop if you run this code, so you'll need to add exit conditions and error handling.

Answer (score 0):

Since JavaScript is inherently **single threaded**, there is no such thing as running a function in parallel to the "main" thread, like you would in multi-threaded languages like C#.

What you could do however, is use `Workers`. Most modern browsers support this feature that allows you to start a new JavaScript process that can run a script.

In order to use it though, you need to isolate the functions you want to run in the background in a new file (e.g. background.js). Then you'd create a Worker by putting this in your `start()` function:

```
start() {
    var backgroundWorker = new Worker('background.js');
}
```

Read more on workers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) like this. It's basic then Promises.

```
function start() {
    loop();
}

function one(){
   // do something
}

function two() {
   // do something
}

function loop() {
    setTimeout(async () => {
        await one();
        await two();
        await loop();
    }, 1000);
}
```